# Can switch bluetooth profile only after 3 times restarting bluetooth

Tags: 16.04, sound, xubuntu, bluetooth

I have a August EP650 bluetooth headset and problems with swichting the audio profile.

I switch between telephony (HSP/HFP) and music listening (A2DP) a lot, so this is quite annoying.

Each time I boot my system, I can switch the profile using the GUI:

[image: Switching Dialog]

In the syslog I get:

```
Aug 16 08:59:20 orange pulseaudio[7711]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c:     
   Transport Acquire() failed for transport 
   /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_12_D0_02_90_27/fd0 (Operation Not Authorized)
```

I already made the modification as suggested [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1526534#p1526534):

```
Edit the file:
/etc/pulse/default.pa
and comment out (with an # at the beginning of the line) the following line:
#load-module module-bluetooth-discover
now edit the file:
/usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11
and after the lines:
   if [ x”$SESSION_MANAGER” != x ] ; then
    /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-xsmp “display=$DISPLAY session_manager=$SESSION_MANAGER” > /dev/null
    fi
add the following line:
    /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

But the problem persists.

Now if I execute around 3 times `sudo service bluetooth restart` and my headset switches off, I can reconnect the headset and the switching works flawlessly.

How can I fix that?

*edit*

`pacmd` -> `list-cards` prints

```
profiles:
    headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (priority 20, available: unknown)
    a2dp_sink: Hi-Fi-Wiedergabe (A2DP-Senken) (priority 10, available: yes)
    off: Aus (priority 0, available: yes)
```

But in the above case I am connected to headset_head_unit - and still cannot change to a2dp_sink

*edit2*

<strike>I found out, that when I remove the module loading from the `x11-pulseaudio` completely and then load the module *after* connection the headset manually via</strike>

```
$ pacmd
Welcome to PulseAudio 8.0! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

it works directly - the question is, how can I automate that?

Comment: Does waiting have any impact? Based on the Arch Linux modification that you linked (and I quote) "This way the Pulse audio’s Bluetooth modules will not be downloaded at boot time but after x11 is started." To me this means that your X11 session will be running prior to the modification going active.

Comment: Waiting how long? Recently I connected the head phone maybe 30 minutes after logging in and it worked directly. Next day around 1 minute - and it did not work.

Comment: I have a very similar problem with a BOHM B-66 headset. In Sound Settings, if I select the headset, then A2DP, I get `Nov  4 13:06:27 snafu pulseaudio[2418]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: Transport Acquire() failed for transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_FC_58_FA_1B_45_4F/fd1 (Operation Not Authorized)` and the sound device reverts to built-in audio. In my case, `sudo service bluetooth restart` seems to fix the issue (i.e., I can select A2DP and it works).

Answer (score 0):

Try it from the command line. You can use `pacmd` to change audio options. The command for changing the default output sink is

```
$ sudo pacmd set-default-sink "OUTPUTNAME"
```

The command for changing the input is

```
$ sudo pacmd set-default-source "SOURCENAME"
```

I think the problem could be that you may not have `sudo` privileges. However, I am not sure if `pacmd` requires root privileges. Try it and tell me if it works.

If you do not know the name of the sink you want, try listing them

```
$ sudo pacmd list-sinks
```

If you need any further help, just let me know in the comments.

Comment: Nope - it is not about the sink - it is about the *profile* on the sink. Sink shows only the headset. What I am talking about is the profile HSP/HFP vs. A2DP - I don't see where to change that in pactl

Answer (score 0):

I found a Workaround that helped me having the same Problem with a Bose OE Soundlink.

Looks like the `module-bluetooth-discover` does only work properly when loaded after X11 session is started.

Therefore you can use the following workaround:

In the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` comment out the line

```
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

so it looks like

```
#load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Then add `/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` in 
the file `/usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11` so it looks like this:

```
set -e

if [ x"$DISPLAY" != x ] ; then

    /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-publish "display=$DISPLAY" > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-bell "display=$DISPLAY" "sample=bell.ogg" > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-cork-request "display=$DISPLAY" > /dev/null

    if [ x"$KDE_FULL_SESSION" = x"true" ]; then
       /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-device-manager "do_routing=1" > /dev/null
    fi

    if [ x"$SESSION_MANAGER" != x ] ; then
    /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-xsmp "display=$DISPLAY session_manager=$SESSION_MANAGER" > /dev/null
    fi
    /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
fi
```

Now it is ensured that `module-bluetooth-discover` is loaded after X11 is started.

Reboot and you should be able to change the profile.

Answer (score -1):

i found that with my plantronics back beat pro headset connecting to a Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 on 16.04 , it will connect at first in HSP mode and will not switch to A2DP unless disconnected and reconnected , then it will allow the switch. I can do this without any real delay using the sound settings control panel applet

This seems to map to the 3 times you have suggested and is consistently repeatable , its not perfect but it does work.

Comment: Does not not work for me or solve it. Can you elaborate how this maps to 3 times restarting? Still I hope there is a solution that works directly.

Comment: 1st time connects as HSP , possibly not allowed by your config , 2nd time disconnects , 3rd time connects as HSP but allows switch.

Comment: HSP is allowed by my config ... if if works, I can switch between both

Comment: for me on the first connect it will not be possible to switch to a2dp , i have to disconnect and reconnect it, then it connects as hsp but allows switch to a2dp

Comment: not all bluetooth chipsets are created equal and quirks abound it seems